# Reset Tensorflow and PyTorch memory stats

Tags: tensorflow, memory-management, pytorch, gpu, out-of-memory

I have a pipeline of machine learning models, where some are written using Tensorflow and some are written using PyTorch. To get a picture of the GPU memory usage throughout the pipeline, I use the provided functions by Tensorflow and PyTorch. As I process multiple cases, I want to reset the memory stats before processing the next case:

(1)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import torch

for x in tf.config.list_logical_devices("GPU"):
    tf.config.experimental.reset_memory_stats(x.name[x.name.index(":") + 1:])
torch.cuda.init()
for x in range(torch.cuda.device_count()):
    torch.cuda.reset_peak_memory_stats(x)
```

When I run the above code snippet, I get `RuntimeError: CUDA error: out of memory` when executing `torch.cuda.init()`. This happens (AFAIK) as Tensorflow is using up the whole GPU memory, and as `torch.cuda.init()` still requires some insignificant amount of memory, it fails to allocate it. I know that Tensorflow provides functions such as `tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(device, bool)` that allows GPU memory to grow as the need arises and also `tf.config.set_logical_device_configuration(device, [tf.config.LogicalDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=100)])` to for example limit the GPU memory usage by Tensorflow to 100 MB or similar. However, both methods fail to prevent the `RuntimeError` from happening. Does anyone have an idea what is going on and what I could do to fix this issue?

The examples I tried to fix it are as follows:

(2)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import torch

for gpu in tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU"):
    tf.config.set_logical_device_configuration(gpu, [tf.config.LogicalDeviceConfiguration(memory_limit=100)])
for x in tf.config.list_logical_devices("GPU"):
    tf.config.experimental.reset_memory_stats(x.name[x.name.index(":") + 1:])
torch.cuda.init()
for x in range(torch.cuda.device_count()):
    torch.cuda.reset_peak_memory_stats(x)
```

(3)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import torch

for gpu in tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU"):
    tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(gpu, True)
for x in tf.config.list_logical_devices("GPU"):
    tf.config.experimental.reset_memory_stats(x.name[x.name.index(":") + 1:])
torch.cuda.init()
for x in range(torch.cuda.device_count()):
    torch.cuda.reset_peak_memory_stats(x)
```

However, as already mentioned, both fail to address the issue of there being no memory available.

Executing the code snippets below individually resetting the memory stats works though:

(4)

```
import torch

torch.cuda.init()
for x in range(torch.cuda.device_count()):
    torch.cuda.reset_peak_memory_stats(x)
```

(5)

```
import tensorflow as tf

for x in tf.config.list_logical_devices("GPU"):
    tf.config.experimental.reset_memory_stats(x.name[x.name.index(":") + 1:])
```